# How to make public connections in java

Tags: java, sockets

I am making a public connection for a computer

So I was making a connection between two computers in java.

The Code for Client is:-

```
public class Client {
Socket socket = null;
ServerSocket server = null;
DataInputStream input = null;
DataInputStream in = null;            // second is because one takes input from user and one from socket
DataOutputStream output = null;

public Client(String addr,int port)
{
try
{
socket = new Socket(addr,port);   //Specifies address and port to connect
input = new DataInputStream(System.in);
output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
//Code to read coming messages continously and printing them
Runnable read = new Runnable(){
public void run()
{
String line = "";
while (!line.equals("over")         // means will work until "over" is recieved
{
line = in.readUTF();
System.out.println("Message Came: "+line);

}
Thread.currentThread().stop();      //To stop current thread so there is no error looping

};
Thread thread = new Thread(read);
thread.start();
String line = "";          //To read message from user
while(!line.equals("over"))
{
line = input.readLine();
output.writeUTF(line);
}

// CLosing connection

socket.close();
in.close();
input.close();
output.close();

}catch(Execption e){
return;                    // loop for trying again and again to connect
}
}
public static void main(String []args)
{

Client client = new Client("192.168.1.7",25565);
}

}
```

So this is all the code for Client
All code is same for server except declaring things and initializing them

Constructer will have 1 value (port)

`ServerSocket server = null;`
While initializing :-

```
server = new ServerSocket(port);
socket = server.accept();
```

All works fine until I am using local conne tion that is my ipv4 address
I know I have to port forward the port I am using and I have enabled it
But when I use public ip then it doesnot works

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please take the time to format your code to make it readable to us. I tried to use a formatter but there's some error in your code that stops the formatter from working.

Comment: `while (!line.equals("over") `, for example, is missing a parenthesis.

Comment: Also, `}catch(Execption e){` should be `Exception`. How in the world is this code compiling? Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Actually I wrote in rough because I hadn't the original code.